# Hibernate: connection.url for SQL Server .MDF File

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, mdf

How do I Hibernate connection.url for SQL Server .MDF File? I've tried

```
prop.setProperty("hibernate.connection.url", "jdbc:sqlserver://c:\\db.mdf");
```

but don't work :(

Thx!

Answer (score 0):

The property `hibernate.connection.url` takes the **JDBC URL** that you have to provide which connects to a database. Read more about it in the [documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-hibernatejdbc).

Eg:

```
hibernate.connection.url = jdbc:postgresql://localhost/mydatabase
```

**[MDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1175882/what-is-an-mdf-file)** file is an internal representation of data in MS SQL Server. You should be connecting to a SQL Server and not the **MDF** file. I have also found a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1972755/how-to-edit-sql-server-primary-database-file-mdf) confirming that **you can not use a MDF file out side the MS SQL Server.**

Comment: How do I use the SQLite .DB file in Hibernate, I thought I could use the SQL Server .MDF file.

Thanks for the reply!

Comment: You are going in wrong direction again. In hibernate you need to connect to the **database server** be it MySQL, SQL Lite or MS SQL Server and not the **physical data file** of the server.